# How do I get the amount of asset i have on the pool?

Tags: ethers.js, javascript, uniswap, polygon, liquidity-provider

I' am trying to retrieve the amount of token i have on my liquidity pool but i don't know how should i do it i've been trying to use the NonFungiblePositionManager but i can't use the token amount only the liquidity.
This is what i would like to get exacly:
[image: the values i want to get]

i would like to get them in that format 0.066 and 1.33 but even if i have the pool Id i can't make it work

i can't get t
he sqrtPriceX96 either from my pool, i don't know what im doing right now